# C / C++ Interview: Code Optimization

Tags: optimization, fizzbuzz

I had an interview today. This question was to optimize the code below. if we will see the code below after for loop there are four steps of "if-else" follows. So, interviewer asked me optimize it to 3 if-else line. I have tried a lot. But could not able to find the solution. Even he told me if you know scripting language then, you can use them also. 
Please help me in optimizing the same.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    for(i; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if((i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0))
        {cout << "PR\n";}
        else if(i % 3 == 0)
        {cout << "P\n";}
        else if(i % 5 == 0)
        {cout << "R\n";}
        else
        {cout << i <<"\n";}
    }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `"P"` and `"R"` be `"F"` and `"B"`, respectively?

Comment: @6502: I didn't get your question

Comment: This is the [FizzBuzz](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz) problem (@6502's "F" and "B" reference).

Comment: Though the assignment is pretty trivial, I daresay that rhe really correct answer is "WTF, outputting to cout takes 10,000 longer than an extra if, that is a useless optimization". In other words, this is probably a catch question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well known question... the "[FizzBuzz](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz)".

You can even solve it without any explicit IFs

```
const char *messages[] = {"%i\n", "P\n", "R\n", "PR\n"};

for (i=1; i<=100; i++) {
    printf(messages[((i % 3)==0) + 2*((i % 5)==0))], i);
}
```

Comment: :- Excellent, I have one question from where did you learn this coding? :)

Comment: Although the claim about avoiding "ifs" is somewhat misleading because internally there is a whole "world" of "ifs" in printf.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, in Python:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    s = ''
    if i % 3 == 0:
        s += 'P'
    if i % 5 == 0:
        s += 'R'
    if i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0:
        s = i
    print(s)
```

Equivalently: using a flag, as shown in your own answer:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    s, flag = '', False
    if i % 3 == 0:
        flag = True
        s += 'P'
    if i % 5 == 0:
        flag = True
        s += 'R'
    if not flag:
        s = i
    print(s)
```

Just for fun, a Python version of @6502's answer:

```
messages = ['{}', 'P', 'R', 'PR']
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(messages[(i%3 == 0) + 2*(i%5 == 0)].format(i))
```

And finally, my personal favorite (because it's the shortest) - using the Greatest Common Divisor function and a lookup table:

```
from fractions import gcd
messages = {3:'P', 5:'R', 15:'PR'}
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(messages.get(gcd(i, 15), i))
```

Comment: I have put my solution after hours of struggle. Please let me know whether it is optimized one or not?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak yes, your answer is correct. I updated my answer above with a Python version, both approaches are equivalent and give the same result

Comment: Thanks Oscar, your answers are very much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.
Please let me know whether it is good or not?

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;int stat=0;
    for(i; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        stat=0;
        if(i%3 == 0){stat++; cout << "P";}
        if(i%5 == 0){stat++; cout << "R";}
        if(stat == 0)cout << i;
        cout << "\n";
    }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but the solution to this problem can be written in a simpler way - there's no need to use `if-else if-else` instructions! see my answer for a couple of options

Answer (score 1):

I really like 6502's answer, but here is a simple solution without extra variables:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    if(i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        continue;
    }

    if(i % 3 == 0)
        printf("P");

    if(i % 5 == 0)
        printf("R");

    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way only use 3 if

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
 {
   bool fizz = (i % 3) == 0;
   bool buzz = (i % 5) == 0;
   if (fizz)
    cout << "Fizz";
   if (buzz)
    cout << "Buzz";
    if (!fizz && !buzz)
     cout << i;
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should jot down what exactly is optimized